# What is the minimal amount of basic checks, i.e "is x < y", that is needed to sort 4 elements in a best-case scenario?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

I received an exercise to provide an algorithm that sorts 4 elements using only comparisons like "is x < y". I drew up a binary tree and my results are that you need 5 comparisons at most, which I know from research online is true.
However, the issue I encountered is that in the best case, my algorithm needs only 3 comparisons to recognize a list that is already sorted properly. For example:

**Input:** {x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4} with the values {1, 2, 3, 4}

**Step 1:** if x_1 < x_2 is true execute Step 2 a).
**Step 2 a):** if x_2 < x_3 is true execute Step 3 a).
**Step 3 a):** if x_3 < x_4 is true sorting is complete.

So in the best case 3 comparisons. But I have read online that the minimal amount is 4 and not 3. Which confuses me. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me. Is the best case truly 3 comparisons or have I made an error in my procedure?

To clarify: Steps after 1 have a and b options to accommodate for both results of the previous step. So Step 2 a) if the first comparison is true and Step 2 b) if the first comparison is false.

I did not provide the entire binary tree as it is very long, but I could do it if necessary.

Comment: "But I have read online that the minimal amount is 4 and not 3." Link?

Comment: Are you sure that your online information didn't say "$O(N)$, instead of actually $N$?

Comment: Your "b" options don't appear to be in the question.

Comment: @Chuu, read until the *very end* of the question.

Comment: Clearly your reference is incorrect if it claims that 4 compares are needed in the best case scenario for a list of 4 elements.

Comment: @Chuu Yes it is supposed to be "execute Step 3 a)" in Step 2. However, every time I try to edit it, it says my post contains code that has not been properly indented. I don't know how to fix that as my post contains no code and just a second ago it allowed me to post it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you very much for the confirmation. I was suspecting it but I wasn't sure. I had a doubt that perhaps a false step in logic allowed me to come to that conclusion.

Comment: What is the use of this question when there is no source for that statement?

Comment: Either the page you read is mistaken, or you have misunderstood what it's saying.

Comment: Having 4 ordered elements means `a < b < c < d`. If you count the number of `<`'s you'll have 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always verify that a list of *n* items is sorted using *n*-1 comparisons, in a way akin to what you've shown. If every pair of adjacent elements is in the correct order, then by induction the list is sorted, and there are *n*-1 adjacent pairs.